# How to Center Align a Nav Bar

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I'd like to use navigation for my footer just like how it is being used as a standard menu for default ASP.NET MVC applications. The styling looks good and it just make sense to me, so sticking with this configuration would be excellent. How might I center this without  modifying the CSS? My concern is that since the header uses `class="nav navbar-nav"` as well, if I adjusted the `nav` CSS to say `text-align:center;` will mess up my main menu at the top of the page. Any recommendations?

Note: I know I've justified my main nav bar menu items previously using something like `style="text-align:center;"` but I cannot remember how.

```
<footer>
        <div class="container-fluid"> //Necessary?
            <div class="row">  //Necessary?
                <div class="col-md-12">  //Necessary?
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="text-align:center;">  //Trying to adjust the style to center align
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a class="dropdown-toggle" role="button" aria-expanded="false" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Home <span class="caret"></span></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Item 1", "Index", "Home", protocol: null, hostName: null, fragment: "item1", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: null)</li>
                                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Item 2", "Index", "Home", protocol: null, hostName: null, fragment: "item2", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: null)</li>
                                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Item 3", "Index", "Home", protocol: null, hostName: null, fragment: "item3", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: null)</li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                        </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</footer>
```

EDIT:

I've discovered that in the `<ul>` tag doing the following creates the look and feel of the basic navbar

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
```

Also, there is are `navbar-left` and `navbar-right` classes which justify the navbar either left or right, but there is no center. Any recommendations on creating a `navbar-center`?

Answer (score 0):

If you can access your css,

```
footer ul li {
text-align:center;
}
```

or from html

```
<div class="row" style="text-align:center;">
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xKSUH/)

Comment: Golden Ball: footer .container-fluid {margin:0 auto; text-align:center;}; It will only work if you have fix width over container-fluid or use % to handle the bar.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code? set the width for the div the width of your nav bar `<div class="col-md-12" style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;width:___;">`